# How to inject custom js files with grunt-wiredep?

Tags: grunt-wiredep, wiredep

Is it possible to inject my own js folder by grunt-wiredep task? Is there solution for it?

**EDIT**

I found [grunt-inject](https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-inject/tree/master/tasks), but I'm using jade view engine(that solution is only for HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it from first glance. Looks like it is exclusively dependent on wiredep which only scans bower.json.

The closest thing you can do is manage other JS dependencies through bower as well.

https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/107

I am also looking for an alternative. I am also looking into grunt-inject, but no longer use jade on my projects.

- https://github.com/ChrisWren/grunt-inject
- https://github.com/klei/grunt-injector
- https://github.com/scott-laursen/grunt-scriptlinker

**If I figure out a jade alternative, and which one I chose, I'll update my post.**